# In React, how to call function based on const value change

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-table

I have 3 components in react. One of them is the parent component and the remaining two are the child components (EziSchedule & EziTransaction), where each component is getting its own data by calling the API. however data to show in child component EziTransaction depends upon what record I click on table in schedule class.

when user click on record in EziSchedule, it goes back to parent component followed by EziTransaction and can print correct id in EziTransaction.

I need to refresh data in EziTransaction component which I am unable to do so. I believe I need to use state changed in order to call getEziTransactionData in EziTransaction component to refresh data but not sure how to do it.

### Parent component

```
const EziTrackerParrent = () =>{
 const [data, setData] = useState('schedule');

useEffect(() =>{
  
},[]);

 return (
  <div>
      <h3>EziSchedule Table</h3>
      <EziSchedule change={setData} ></EziSchedule>

      <h3>EziTransaction Table</h3>
      <EziTransaction data={data}></EziTransaction>
  </div>
  )
```

### Child Component A - EziSchedule

Capture click event and pass it to parent

```
   const EziSchedule = ({change}) =>{
```

### Child Component B - EziTransaction

Get data from EziSchidule on click event via parent component. I need help here to ensure very time 'data' value changes, It call getEziTransactionData() and refresh html

```
const EziTransaction = ({data}) =>{

const [eziTransactionData, setEziTransactionData] = useState<IEziTransaction[]>();

useEffect(() => {
    getEziTransactionData();  // this method call API to get data 
},[]);

 const getEziTransactionData = ()=>{  // I need to call this everytime user click on record in EziSchedule???
  (async () =>{
  try{
        const result = //API Call... 
        setEziTransactionData(result);
    ........

   return(
    <div>
        <div>I have received "{data}" from parent</div>  // this values does change every click in EziSchedule
```

Answer (score 2):

to trigger `getEziTransactionData` everytime `data`updates you need to pass `data` as dependency at `useEffect`

```
useEffect(() => {
    getEziTransactionData();
},[data]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run the useEffect hook on props/state change by adding that variable in dependency array if the useEffect hook.
In your case you can add `data` to dependency of useEffect and useEffect will run every time the variable `data` changes.
If you are using `data` in your method to make api call, you can make that function a callback and just add that function to the dependency of useEffect, so every time data will change, your callback function will change, which will trigger the useEffect hook.

```
const EziTransaction = ({data}) => {

  const [eziTransactionData, setEziTransactionData] = useState<IEziTransaction[]>();

  // wrap this function in a useCallback hook
  const getEziTransactionData = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      const result = await fetchApiData(data) // assuming you are using `data` in your API Call, if not add it to useEffect dependency and remove from this callback's dependency
      setEziTransactionData(result);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  }, [setEziTransactionData, data]); // set dependency array of callback properly

  useEffect(() => {
    getEziTransactionData();
  },[getEziTransactionData]); // set dependency array properly

  return(
    <div>
        <div>I have received "{data}" from parent</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in addition to the answer below i would recomend to define you fetch function inside `useEffect` with `data` dependency to avoid extra memoization

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const getEziTransactionData = async () => {
      try {
        const result = await fetchApiData(data);
        setEziTransactionData(result);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    });

    getEziTransactionData();
  }, [data]);
```